# Is checkpoint being saved for every partition in JEE Batch Processing?

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-processing

If I have a simple JEE Batch job, with a step that can process data in parallel.

I want to read data from different sources and as they are independent - it can be done simultaneously in several threads.

Step:

```
<step id="step1">
  <chunk checkpoint-policy="item" item-count="15">
    <reader ref="MyReader">
      <properties>
        <!-- some properties -->
      </properties>
    </reader>
    <processor ref="MyProcessor"></processor>
    <writer ref="MyWriter"></writer>
  </chunk>
  <partition>
    <mapper ref="MyPartitionMapper"/>
  </partition>
</step>
```

And let's say, my `reader`, is using the `checkpoint` because in case of error I want to restart the partition and process only data which haven't been already read and processed.

**Question:**
If I have such scenario (several data sources, reading in parallel), can I restart the job or the partition in case of error with checkpoint saved for this specific partition?

In other words, even if I have to restart the job, will I have separate checkpoint saved for each partition, so for each data source, I read only new data (not already processed)?

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering the answer to this very question, so I dug into the [JSR 352 standard](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/batch-1_0_revA-mrel-eval-spec/JSR_352-v1.0_Rev_a-Maintenance_Release.pdf).  To quote:

> Since each thread runs a separate copy of the step, chunking and checkpointing occur independently on each thread for chunk type steps.

[JBeret's PartitionExecutionImpl](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/jberet-core/src/main/java/org/jberet/runtime/PartitionExecutionImpl.java) class shows this data being stored for each partition, based on the index.  So long as the index is consistent across runs, the checkpoints should be per partition.